# Use attributes for value tuples

Tags: c#, functional-programming, tuples, resharper

In C# 7.0, .NET introduces a new return value tuple types (functional programming), so instead of:

```
[NotNull]
WrapperUser Lookup(int id)
```

I'd like to use value tuples:

```
(User, Info) Lookup(int id)
```

And I want to use attributes for these return types:

```
([NotNull] User, [CanBeNull] Info) Lookup(int id)
```

But VS2017 doesn't allow me to do it. How can I use attributes without using a wrapper class?

Comment: Now that it's 2019 with C# 8.0 with non-nullable support, I'm curious how it implements non-nullable vs nullable reference type members of `ValueTuple`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

```
(User, Info) Lookup(int id)
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
ValueTuple<User,Info> Lookup(int id)
```

The type parameters of `ValueTuple` are not valid targets for attributes. Your only option besides a wrapper class is to wrap the type parameters in a [NonNullable wrapper](https://web.archive.org/web/20081231232311/http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/06/non-nullable-reference-types.aspx)

```
(NonNullable<User>,NonNullable<Info>) Lookup(int id)
```

which allows you to use it just like a normal `ValueTuple`, e.g.

```
(NonNullable<User>,NonNullable<Info>) Lookup(int id) => (new User(), new Info());
(User user, Info info) = Lookup(5);
```

Otherwise you could stick a custom attribute to the whole `ValueTuple` indicating which tuple elements can be `null` with an array, like the [`TupleElementNamesAttribute`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/Test/Resources/Core/NetFX/ValueTuple/TupleElementNamesAttribute.cs) that is used to assign names to the tuple elements. You would have to write your own visual studio / resharper plugin that does the work though.